# RKHS lying in another RKHS

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, kernels

Suppose $H_1$ and $H_2$ are reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces such that $H_1 \subset H_2$. For $f \in H_1$, when can I bound $\|f \|_1$ with $C\|f\|_2$ (for some $C$)? Is there a relationship between inducing kernels $k_1$ and $k_2$ that would imply this?

Comment: I'd like first to confirm that by $H_1\subset H_2$, you meant that the elements in both $H_1$ and $H_2$ are functions on a common set, say $\Omega$. Then I believe you always have the existence of a constant $C>0$ such that $\|f\|_{1}\leq C\|f\|_2$ for all $f\in H_1$. This should follow from the Closed Graph Theorem: the inclusion map from $H_1$ into $H_2$ is closed due to the fact that norm convergence implies pointwise convergence.